# Counting Inversions Using Merge Sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have made a merge sort program in Python and it is running perfectly but I have modified it to count the number of inversions involved and now it is giving me an error :

Here's my code:

```
def merge_list(left,right,c):
    result=[]
    i,j=0,0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            print "Left result",result
            i=i+1
        elif left[i] > right[j]:
            result.append(right[j])
            print "Right result",result
            j=j+1
        if right[j] < left[i]  and i<j:
            c=c+1
    result=result+left[i:]
    result=result+right[j:]
    print "Inversions: ",c
    return result,c


def sort_and_count(lis,count):

    if len(lis)<2:
        return lis
    middle=len(lis) / 2
    left,c1=sort_and_count(lis[:middle],count)
    print "left",left
    right,c2=sort_and_count(lis[middle:],count)
    print "right",right
    m,c=merge_list(left,right,count)
    c=c+c1+c2
    return m,c


if __name__=="__main__":

    print "Enter 6 elements: "
    i=0;lis=[];merge_lis=[];inv=0
    while i<=5:
        x=int(raw_input())
        lis.append(x)
        i=i+1
    count=0
    merge_lis,inv=sort_and_count(lis,count)
    print "Sorted list is: ",merge_lis,inv
```

And my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sort_and_count.py", line 53, in <module> 
    merge_lis,inv=sort_and_count(lis,count) 
  File "Sort_and_count.py", line 31, in sort_and_count 
    left,c1=sort_and_count(lis[:middle],count) 
  File "Sort_and_count.py", line 31, in sort_and_count
    left,c1=sort_and_count(lis[:middle],count)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Where am I going wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
return lis
```

This is a problem, because you are expecting `sort_and_count` to return a tuple containing two values, so when it returns only one value you have a problem with the tuple unpacking in lines like `left,c1=sort_and_count(lis[:middle],count)`.  This line should return two values, like the last line of that method:

```
return m,c
```

Comment: Thank you for you valuable answer. This has resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you've implemented wrong algorithm to count the number of inversions.

1) In function `merge_list` instead of:

```
elif left[i] > right[j]:
    result.append(right[j])
    print "Right result",result
    j=j+1
if right[j] < left[i]  and i<j:
    c=c+1
```

you should use this code:

```
elif right[j] < left[i]:
    result.append(right[j])
    j += 1
    inv_count += (len(left)-i)
```

2) Function `merge_list` doesn't need variable `c` as an input.

3) Function `sort_and_count` doesn't need variable `count` as an input.

Try this code:

```
def merge_list(left,right):
    result = list()
    i,j = 0,0
    inv_count = 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
            inv_count += (len(left)-i)
    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]
    return result,inv_count


def sort_and_count(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array, 0
    middle = len(array) // 2
    left,inv_left = sort_and_count(array[:middle])
    right,inv_right = sort_and_count(array[middle:])
    merged, count = merge_list(left,right)
    count += (inv_left + inv_right)
    return merged, count


if __name__=="__main__":
    array = [2,3,1,4,5]
    merge_array,inversions = sort_and_count(array)
    print 'Start with array: %s;\nSorted array:     %s;\nInversions: %s.'%(array,merge_array,inversions)
```

Comment: could you add some bullet points of what is different between your code and the code in question?

Comment: I've changed my comment a little bit. Is it better now?

Comment: better, yes, but after seeing the other answers, they look significantly more concise.  still, you raise a good point, that `merge_list` doesn't need `count`

Comment: if left[i] <= right[j]: enables you to treat equalities. Otherwise the algorithm will run forever.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that `sort_and_count` is only returning a single value. There are only two returns in the function, so the culprit is this one:

```
if len(lis)<2:
    return lis
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
return lis
```

do

```
return lis, count
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're returning a single value where he's expecting two.

Look at

```
def sort_and_count(lis,count):
    if len(lis) < 2:
        return lis
    middle = len(lis) / 2
   left, c1 = sort_and_count(lis[:middle],count)
   # etc
```

If you call sort_and_count([1], count), the len(lis) will be < 2 and it will return the single-element list, but will not return a count, which is expected in the call below.

Just return a value for c1 like

```
return lis, count # do your things with count
```