# counting inversions of mergesort

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

I have implemented a mergesort function which works correctly, However, I'm having a hard time modifying it to count the number of inversions in the original array before it is sorted.

An inversion is a pair where `i < j but a[i] > a[j]` an example, `a = [5,2,1]` has 3 inversions: `(5,2),(5,1),(2,1)`

```
def mergeSort(a):

    mid = len(a)//2

    if len(a) < 2:
        return

    l = a[:mid]
    r = a[mid:]
    mergeSort(l)
    mergeSort(r)

    return merge(l,r,a)

def merge(l,r,a):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    inv = 0

    while(i < len(l) and j < len(r)):
        if(l[i] < r[j]):
           a[k] = l[i]
           i = i + 1
        else:
            a[k] = r[j]
            inv = inv + 1
            j = j + 1
        k = k + 1

    while i < len(l):
        a[k] = l[i]
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
    while j < len(r):
       a[k] = r[j]
       j = j + 1
       k = k + 1
       inv = inv + 1
    return [a,inv]

a = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
print(mergeSort(a))
```

The above example should return 15 as the count of inversions as n(n-1)/2 is the number of inversions for descending order array.

can someone explain how to count it?

Comment: There is a code for the same problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733119/counting-inversions-using-merge-sort) post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L[i] > R[j]` is a single inversion, but note that since the arrays are sorted, if `L[k] > R[j]` for some `k`, this means `L[k] > R[j] for all i <= k < |L|`. So you can subtract the length of the array `L` from `i` to give you the total number of inversions.